# How to make the nzAction to real api in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code:

***HTML***

```
      <nz-upload class="avatar-uploader" nzType="drag" nzName="avatar" nzListType="picture-card"
        nzAction="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" [nzShowUploadList]="false"
        [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload" (nzChange)="uploadHandleChange($event)">

        <ng-container *ngIf="!avatarUrl">
          <p class="ant-upload-drag-icon">
            <i nz-icon [nzType]="loading ? 'loading' : 'inbox'"></i>
          </p>
          <div class="ant-upload-text">
            <b>Choose a file</b>
            or drag it here to upload.
          </div>
        </ng-container>

        <img *ngIf="avatarUrl" [src]="avatarUrl" class="avatar" />

      </nz-upload>
```

***TS***

```
 beforeUpload = (file: File) => {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      const imageType = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'].includes(file.type);

      // console.log(imageType);
      // if ()
      observer.next(imageType)
      observer.complete();
      console.log(imageType)
    });
  }

  getBase64(img: File, callback: (img: string) => void): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result!.toString()));
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
  }

  uploadHandleChange(info: { file: UploadFile }): void {
    switch (info.file.status) {
      case 'uploading':
        this.loading = true;
        break;
      case 'done':
        // Get this url from response in real world.
        this.getBase64(info.file!.originFileObj!, (img: string) => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.avatarUrl = img;
        });
        break;
      case 'error':
        console.log('Network error');
        this.loading = false;
        break;
    }
  }
```

The problem here is when I try to upload a photo, the error is "http://newbie-test.com:8093/apihttps://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"

But when I remove the nzAction, when I try to upload it doesn't work.